# Critical points, open and closed interval

Tags: calculus

I know that end-points on a closed interval $[a,b]$ are critical points, but what about end points on an open interval $(a,b)$?

I remember my teacher saying that they are also considered to critical points but since $a$ and $b$ are not in the domain of the function how can this be true?

Comment: In fact, it's not true... For *critical points* are either points in which $f$ is defined but not differentiable or points in which $f$ is defined, differentiable and has null derivative (the latter are the socalled *stationary points*).

Comment: I was told that critical points are all points that 

$f'(x) = 0, f'(x)$ undefined or end points on an interval of a domain

Comment: The end points of the domain are critical points only when they actually belong to the domain (in such a case, they are points in which the function is defined but the derivative isn't properly defined as the two-sided limit of the difference quotient).

Let's try to be more heuristic. You want to say that a point is *critical* when a function can possibly attain its (local) minimum or its (local) maximum **at that point**... So, how can a point where the function is not defined ever be critical? It's nonsense, because a function doesn't attain any value in any point outside its domain! ;-D

Comment: Say I have a function $f$ that is defined and strictly increasing from $(a, b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ 

Would $f(a)$ be considered a min and $f(b)$ be a max for the function $f(x)$? If not what would they be?

Comment: If $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$, then the symbols $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ do not have a meaning at all...

Comment: Then what is the min/max of $f$ over it's domain?

Comment: Simply, they don't exist at all. Just to give you an example, let $f:(-1,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x) := arctan \frac{x}{1-x^2}$: it is quite evident that $f$ is strictly increasing in $(-1,1)$ and that $\displaystyle \sup_{(-1,1)} f = \frac{\pi}{2}=\lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x)$, $\displaystyle \inf_{(-1,1)} f = -\frac{\pi}{2} = \lim_{x\to-1^+} f(x)$; nevertheless, neither $f(1)$ nor $f(-1)$ has a meaning (because division by $0$ is not allowed).

Comment: Another example, which is more tricky, is the following. Let $f:(-1,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ be definied by $f(x):=x$: it is quite evidente that $f$ is strictly increasing in $(-1,1)$ and that $\displaystyle \sup_{(-1,1)} f = 1=\lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x)$, $\displaystyle \inf_{(-1,1)} f = -1 = \lim_{x\to-1^+} f(x)$; nevertheless, $f$ doesn't have minimum or maximum, because $\pm 1$ don't lie in the domain of $f$ and, therefore, you are not allowed to evaluate neither $f(1)$ nor $f(-1)$ (although the explicit formula for $f(x)$ does actually have a meaning even for $x=\pm 1$).

Answer (score 1):

By definition a point $x_0$ is a *critical point* of $f$ if $f$ is defined in some open neighborhood of $x_0$, and $f'(x_0)=0$.

Faced with an extremal problem for a continuous function $f:\>[a,b]\to{\mathbb R}$ you set up a **candidate list**  consisting of (i) the critical points of $f$ in $\ ]a,b[\ $, (ii) the points $a$ and $b$, and (iii) the points in $\ ]a,b[\ $ where $f$ is not differentiable. If the resulting list $S$ is **finite**, i.e., $S=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_m\}$ for some $m\in{\mathbb N}$, then
$$\max_{a\leq x\leq b}f(x)=\max_{1\leq i\leq m}f(x_i)\ ,$$
and similarly for the minimum. Note that we don't need to compute second derivatives in this process.

Comment: That is not how critical points are defined nowadays. 
"critical points are all points that f′(x)=0,f′(x) undefined or end points on an interval of a domain"

Answer (score 0):

The maximum or minimum values of a function can occur at the endpoints $a$ and $b$ or the interior $(a,b)$, obviously. If $x\in (a,b)$ is a critical point, then the derivative $f'(x)=0$ or $f'(x)$ is undefined. It is these $x$ values, that we call critical points.

Comment: But $a \notin  (a,b), x=a $ is still considered to be a critical point? That's what I'm trying to ask, apparently it is considered one.

Comment: Most authors don't define the end points as critical points. A differentiable function can attain a local max or min at the end points, or the critical points, and the latter belong to $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher probably wants you to consider the endpoints as critical points because on a closed interval like that, a function may take a maximum or minimum value at those endpoints. I've seen that the definition of "critical point" can vary in different calculus texts.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that this person's teacher didn't communicate clearly.  a and b are not critical numbers if the interval is open.  But for a problem where you need to find an absolute maximum or minimum, the endpoints still need to be considered even if they're not in the domain, because they could show that the function *has no max or min* on the open interval.

For example, f(x)=x^2 has its [-1, 5] at the critical number x=5.  But f(x)=x^2 has no maximum on (-1, 5) because of the open endpoints.  If you didn't bother to check the endpoints because they're not critical points, then you might not realize the lack of maximum value.  I expect the teacher meant for you to check the endpoints in a problem such as this *even though they are not critical points*, and just misspoke.

Comment: edit: has its max* on [-1,5] at the critical number x = 5